# RDS Postgres Logical Replication into EC2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, database-replication, postgresql-9.5, wal

I'm using postgres 9.5.7 in RDS and want to create a slave/read replica on an EC2 box. I've figured out how to get logical replication working on RDS and am able to use `pg_recvlogical` to tap into the replication slot on the EC2 box.

My challenge now has been that, unfortunately, RDS doesn't support `pglogical` and it seems that I'm left with either `test_decoding` or `wal2json` for my output formats. Is there something out there that knows how to take either of those formats and turn them into SQL that can be executed on the slave?

Most of the guides I've found online only go as far as getting `pg_recvlogical` working, and don't take that extra last step of showing how to actually get those changes into the slave database.

Comment: Upgrade to v10 and use logical replication?

Comment: were you able replicate RDS to EC2? If yes, please share steps/doc for reference. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you want to check https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Logical_Decoding_Plugins#decoder_raw

this plugins output a sql statements that can be run in slave postgres